# default to Python 3.9

Tags: ubuntu, python, version-control

I have an ubuntu 20.04 Desktop that comes with Python 3.8 by default.

How do I make Python 3.9 default Python? I had to install this manually.

When I SSH into the machine I was just run `alias python=python3.9` in terminal to temporarily make Python 3.9 default. How do I get rid of this step? I don't need Python 3.8 at all, like it could be removed.

Comment: Try: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
to get rid of old packages.  Restart when done.

Comment: I ran the command you listed but after the reboot typing `python` into terminal Python 3.8.5 is still default. Any ideas to try? Thanks

Comment: I do not know for certain. Try removing Python:  sudo apt remove python[version] and then again sudo apt autoremove.  That may remove the older version.

Comment: @John afaik you should never remove the python version that comes with ubuntu. ubuntu needs it and it may break your distro install